# create a sort and then retrieve first n method for a List<T> where T: IComparable <T>

Tags: c#

I want to write a generic method with the following signature :

```
IList<T> Sort<T> (IList<T> list) where T: IComparable <T>
```

that returns a sorted list. 
sorry for the incomplete original post.
so I want to sort the list and then select the first n elements
that would be

```
        List<T> temp = new List<T>(list);
        temp.Sort();
        List<T> temp2 = new List<T>(temp);
        temp2.Take(count);
```

the complete question would be how to do that without double - copying the initial list.
there would be 2 cases :
the list has dupes and I want to retrieve the first n distinct values 
the list has dupes and I want to retrieve the first n values.
for the first case a distinct should be applied also - so a new "third "copy of list to be avoided.

of course the answer posted by guffa is accepted, because the OP at first was incomplete.

Comment: Do you want to sort in-place or create a new list?

Comment: There's already a Sort() method available on any IList instance (via IEnumerable and System.Linq)

Comment: @SLasks: Only judging from the method signature, the method should return a new list and leave the original untouched.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: Do you mean the `OrderBy` method?

Comment: @Guffa Umm... yeah. Oops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new `List<T>` from the input and sort it:

```
public IList<T> Sort<T> (IList<T> list) where T: IComparable <T> {
  List<T> temp = new List<T>(list);
  temp.Sort();
  return temp;
}
```

The `Sort` method will use the default comparer when you don't specify one, which uses the `IComparable<T>` implementation if there is one.

#### Edit:

To answer the edited question:

You have to copy the list twice if you want to preserve the input and return a list.

You could get around the second copying if you return `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IList<T>`. Then you can return a deferred result that reads from the first copy of the list. The drawback is of course that it will keep the entire first list in memory although you only use a part of it.

Anyway, the version returning an `IList<T>` would be something like:

```
public IList<T> Sort<T> (IList<T> list, int cnt, bool distinct) where T: IComparable <T> {
  IEnumerable<T> temp = list.OrderBy(t => t);
  if (distinct) {
    temp = temp.Distinct();
  }
  return temp.Take(cnt).ToList();
}
```

For the version returning an `IEnumerable<T>` you would just not do the `.ToList()` in the last step.